# Why is QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor still alive after app.quit()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have a PyQt5 QWebEnginePage with a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor. After running app.exec_(), the Interceptor works as intended, but after the page finishes loading, that is, the callback 
 in `self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)` is executed, and `self.app.quit()` is ran, the `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor.interceptRequest()` function is called again, resulting in the Error `Received signal 11 <unknown> 000000000000`
 and the script crashing.

```
class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, on_network_call):
        super().__init__()
        self.on_network_call = on_network_call

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        self.on_network_call(info)


class PyQtWebClient(QWebEnginePage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(self.on_network_call)
    profile = QWebEngineProfile()
    profile.setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)

    super().__init__(profile, None)

    self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
    self.html = ""

    self.network_requests = {}

    self.load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def on_network_call(self, info):
    # Something ...


  def _on_load_finished(self):
    self.toHtml(self.callable)

  def callable(self, html_str):
    self.html = html_str
    self.app.quit()
```

Tried `PyQt5.11.2` and `PyQt5.10.1`
I expected one of two things:
- self.loadFinished should not be called if there are still pending requests on the page.
- if the self.loadFinished is called and my app exists, the interceptor's thread should stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`loadFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#loadFinished) indicates that the content of the page has finished loading as indicated by the docs:

> #### void QWebEnginePage::loadFinished(bool ok)
>
> This signal is emitted when the page finishes loading content. This
>   signal is independent of script execution or page rendering. ok will
>   indicate whether the load was successful or any error occurred.

But that does not mean that the page keeps making requests, for example you could make requests through AJAX, so do not confuse those concepts.

In the case QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor could be solving pending requests since that part is not handled by Qt but by chromium.

One problem that I see in your code is that QWebEngineProfile is destroyed before QWebEnginePage is destroyed causing problems. The solution in this case is to make the profile and interceptor members of the class.

```
class PyQtWebClient(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(self.on_network_call)
        self.profile = QWebEngineProfile()
        self.profile.setRequestInterceptor(self.interceptor)

        super().__init__(self.profile, None)
        # ...
```

Finally I recommend using the latest version of [PyQt5 5.13.0](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) and [PyQtWebEngine 5.13.0](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtwebengine/download) as it brings improvements such as thread-safe and page specific url request interceptors.

Comment: As you said, I overlooked that my `interceptor` and `profile` were dying after the constructor exited. I will look into upgrading to 5.13, but it seems the library structure is different, so I will defer it for now. I have posted a different question you might be able to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923879/how-to-capture-the-response-of-a-request-intercepted-by-qwebengineurlrequestinte . Thank You!