# How to capture the response of a request intercepted by QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have a PyQt5 QWebEngineProfile with a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor. This interceptor gives me access to the request before it it resolved. Is it possible to capture the response of every request intercepted without having to manually re-submit the request?

```
class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, on_network_call):
        super().__init__()
        self.on_network_call = on_network_call

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        self.on_network_call(info)


class PyQtWebClient(QWebEnginePage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    self.interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(self.on_network_call)
    self.profile = QWebEngineProfile()
    self.profile.setRequestInterceptor(self.interceptor)

    super().__init__(self.profile, None)

    self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
    self.html = ""

    self.network_requests = {}

    self.load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def on_network_call(self, info):
    # Something ...


  def _on_load_finished(self):
    self.toHtml(self.callable)

  def callable(self, html_str):
    self.html = html_str
    self.app.quit()
```

PyQt5 Version: `5.11.2`

Comment: What do you mean by "manually re-submit the request"? What exactly is it that your example fails to achieve?

Comment: `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` allows me to see the request before it resolves. If i want the contents of the response for any specified request, my current solution is to submit the intercepted request a second time using the requests module `requests.get(info.requestUrl().toString())`, but I suspect this is unnecessary since the `QWebEnginePage` already submitted the request and got a response, all I need is to be able to access that response.

Comment: I have a similar issue, were you able to read the response contents without a second manual request in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is nothing like `ResponseInterceptor` that would behave like the `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`. I have been manually submitting them.